# How do I select the device LogCat is showing in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm using eclipse for Android development.  Often I have several emulators (and devices) running in order to test my app.

LogCat magically switches to the log from the device I just launched the app on.  This is fine most of the time, but sometimes I want to switch back to a different device without restarting an app.

I can't figure out where to select which device LogCat is showing. Where can I change it?

I'm using Eclipse Juno on OS X, if that makes any difference.  Here's what my LogCat window looks like:
[image: logcat screenshot]

Comment: You can also specify on the command line using `adb -s [deviceSerialNumber] logcat`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Window -> Show View -> Devices`.

Now you'll have another devices tab present, and in that you can select which device you want to see in the LogCat, as well as the running apps on that device in debug mode.

Comment: by default this window is open on the DDMS perspective.

Comment: True, but he might not be using the DDMS perspective.

Comment: Perfect, thank you both.  I didn't know about the DDMS perspective, but will definitely come in handy in the future.